# foreach statement for data_ItemDataBound for each row in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void data_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    //if (data.Items.Count > 0)
    //{
    //foreach (DataListItem item in (dt.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[0])
    //{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
         DataListItem dt = e.Item;                    

         Label accept = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("acceptYN");

         if (accept.Text == "0")
         {
             (e.Item.FindControl("acceptbut") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl).Visible = true;
             (e.Item.FindControl("confirm") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl).Visible = false;
         }
         else
         {
             (e.Item.FindControl("confirm") as Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl).Visible = true;
             (e.Item.FindControl("acceptbut") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl).Visible = false;
         }
     }
//}
//}
}
```

[e.item.datalist.row.thearray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5KAI.jpg)

Comment: I'm sure you haven't read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a **question** ....don't just dump a heap of code on us - **explain** (in plain English) what you're trying to do, and what issues you encounter, where you are stuck and need help

Comment: provide the details what you suppose to do, and what is the issue

Comment: I have 3 orders from user in which package 1000 is accepted by a cook and package 200 and 100 are not yet accepted by any cooks. 

->Issue
the button (Accepted cooks) is fluctuating for packages....in which it is showing for package 100 and invisible for package  200